# Prevent coercion

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Assuming:

```
Function Invoke-Foo {
  Param(
    [string[]]$Ids
  )
  Foreach ($Id in $Ids) {    
    Write-Host $Id
  }
}
```

If I do this:

```
PS> Invoke-Foo -ids '0000','0001'
0000
0001
```

If I do this:

```
PS> Invoke-Foo -ids 0000,0001
0
1
```

In the second case, is there a way to prevent the coercion, other than make them explicit strings (first case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, unfortunately not.

From the [`about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) help file:

> ```
> When processing a command, the Windows PowerShell parser operates
> in expression mode or in argument mode: 
>
>     - In expression mode, character string values must be contained in
>       quotation marks. Numbers not enclosed in quotation marks are treated
>       as numerical values (rather than as a series of characters). 
>
>     - In argument mode, each value is treated as an expandable string 
>       unless it begins with one of the following special characters: dollar
>       sign ($), at sign (@), single quotation mark ('), double quotation
>       mark ("), or an opening parenthesis (().
> ```

So, the parser evaluates `0001` before anything is passed to the function. We can test the effect of treating `0001` as an "Expandable String" with the `ExpandString()` method:

```
PS C:\> $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(0001)
1
```

Comment: Good answer, vote up, but the ouput would be 0. :) Can not edit it by myself since the edit must be at least 6 characters

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina Thanks, and yes, I just noticed, fixed now :)

Answer (score 3):

At least, if you are sure that your ids are in the range [0, 9999], you can do the formatting like this:

```
Function Invoke-Foo {
    Param([int[]]$Ids)
    Foreach ($Id in $Ids) {    
        Write-Host ([System.String]::Format("{0:D4}", $Id))
    }
}
```

More about padding numbers with leading zeros can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx).

What important to note here:

1. Padding will work for numbers. I changed the parameter typing to `int[]` so that if you pass the strings they will be converted to numbers and the padding will work for them too.
2. This method (as it is now) limits you to the range of ids I mentioned before and it always will give you four-zeros-padded output, even if you pass it '003'